# How to describe the widest measurement of an irregular shape fabric folded in half?

Tags: phrase-request

Sorry if I sound confusing. I can't describe it succinctly.

Let's say I have a piece of cloth in irregular shape. I've to provide the measurement of the fabric in half. To measure, I flatten the fabric, fold into half and measure the widest width. I have difficulties describing it succinctly.

I can only manage the following:

> 100cm (folded half. Measured flatten widest side to side)

I know that doesn't sound right.

------- **UPDATE** --------

Thanks everyone for your patience and guidance. I, to the best of my ability, came up with the diagram. The red line is the measurement I have been referring to.
[image]

How can I describe this to someone? For instance, when I want to talk to them over the phone to:

1. provide instruction for them to take the measurement
2. tell them this measurement is taken from ________

I have also thought of another measurement that I wonder if there is a proper term for it. The measurement of a bag's handle like the diagram. If one is to say the strap's length, or the chain's length, will it be understood as the red line shown in the diagram or it will be interpreted as the full length of the strap/chain measured from one end to another end?

Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: This is my version, **100cm folded in half, measured and widely flattened from side-to-side** (you should add a hyphen here).

Comment: How do you define "folding in half" for an irregular shape?

Comment: Thanks @SorryI'mDumb! I'm not sure about *widely flattened*, do you mind to explain that more if is ok?

Comment: Thanks @JackO'Flaherty! I reckon the *half* will be using the widest section as reference point?

Comment: "widely flattened" doesn't seem very natural; I think just "flattened" would do. To indicate something is measured at its widest part you'd say "measured at the widest part" or "at most" or "at its widest" or "at the widest part" depending on context. **100cm at its widest, when folded in half and flattened**.

Comment: If you mean folded on the line of its largest diameter, that distance will be the same whether you fold it or not.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking.  I'm not sure what *I have to provide the measurement in half,* means.  You might have better luck if you provide a graphic of the original *shape* along with a graphic of that shape folded and then indicate what it is you would like to measure on the folded shape.

Comment: @EllieK Thanks for the input. I've provided a diagram and hopefully it helps to illustrate what I was trying to say.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Will it be the same if is measured width wise? I've worded my question poorly but honestly, that was the best i can manage. I've provided a diagram and hopefully it helps to illustrate what I was trying to say. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks @StuartF I've provided the diagram to illustrate what I was referring to. Thanks so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see an English Learning question here at all. There is a hard to define measurement, and there is no easy way to define it! As a quick test: if this is no easier to define in your native language, then the problem is not a problem of expressing yourself in English, and so not a question that can be solved by learning English better.  The solution to the problem is not clever words in English, but drawing pictures.  There is no ELL question, I VTC

Answer (score 0):

Much better with the examples!

If I was going to describe how you are measuring your example, I would say the following -

> Find the shape's greatest distance from one point to another then divide that distance by two (or in half).

If I wanted to tell someone how to fold your example, I would say -

> Find the shape's greatest distance from one point to another and then fold the shape in half by joining those two points together.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question I would ask for the largest diameter of the fabric. That calls for no folding. You can then ask for a fold perpendicular to that diameter if the fold is what's important.

For the second question I would ask the person to hang the bag from a hook and measure the distance from the hook to the bag. Equivalently, ask them to lay the bag out flat, extend the strap and measure the distance to its farthest point.